# Visual Studio can not connect to SQL Server 2017

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2017

I have installed SQL Server 2017 & when I try to make a connection to a database from Visual Studio 2013, I am getting an error as the screenshot shows. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Dear marc_s , I would be much grateful if you give a answer for the question while you were trying to be smart by editing the question.